# смещение элементов при масштабировании

Tags: css

Почему при масштабировании браузерного окна элементы **.point** съезжают с вертикальной прямой по центру **.timeline_list:before**? Ширина контейнера и обёртки в %, left и right у **.point** тоже в % (в px тот же эффект). В таких ситуациях тоже media queries следует применять?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#timeline {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1100px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.timeline_list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
}

.timeline_list:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
  left: calc(50% - 1px);
}

.timeline_item {
  width: 48%;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  height: min-content;
}

.timeline_item--left {
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.timeline_item--right {
  color: green;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.timeline_item>.point {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.timeline_item--left>.point {
  top: 0;
  /*   right: -24px; */
  right: -6.6%;
  background-color: red;
}

.timeline_item--right>.point {
  top: 0;
  /*   left: 24px; */
  left: -6.6%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<main id="timeline">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="timeline_list">
      <li class="timeline_item timeline_item--left">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo, dolores.</p>
        <div class="point"></div>
      </li>
      <li class="timeline_item timeline_item--right">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate, maiores?</p>
        <div class="point"></div>
      </li>
      <li class="timeline_item timeline_item--left">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex, pariatur?</p>
        <div class="point"></div>
      </li>
      <li class="timeline_item timeline_item--right">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, ipsa?</p>
        <div class="point"></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну я объяснить не могу но делается это не сложно ...смотрите

что бы проверить адаптивность данной вёрстки откройте на всю страницу а сам браузер сожмите ...

эксперементировал вот здесь: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/oRLLyL

```css
* {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.items {
  width: 540px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.items:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 4px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: 0;
  background: #cc0000;
  z-index: 0;
}

.marker {
  display: block;
  min-width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: blue;
  margin: 0 4px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  width: 290px;
}

.item:nth-child(odd) {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.item:nth-of-type(even) {
  text-align: right
}

@media(max-width: 555px) {
  .marker {
    min-width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
  .items {
    width: 373px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  .item {
    width: 200px;
  }
  .text {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="marker"></div>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui tenetur nemo placeat tempora reiciendis?
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae officiis atque fuga odio illo.
    </div>
    <div class="marker"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="marker"></div>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui tenetur nemo placeat tempora reiciendis?
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae officiis atque fuga odio illo.
    </div>
    <div class="marker"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: маркеры все равно немного гуляют. у вас нет?

Comment: @urpride  у меня нет ...покажите скрин

Comment: у .marker поменял margin: 0 4px на 0 5px и все заиграло)